# What gas expands most in a vacuum?

Tags: home-experiment

Layman here.  I need a gas that occupies the most volume under the least pressure.

I am trying to design a water-conservation toilet. i.e- using grey-water from the tub to fill a tank above the toilet.
I want it to be VACUUM driven, so no pumps.
If the storage tank is (say) 1/2 gas and 1/2 grey-water.  I need a gas that will expand to the FULL tank volume, creating a vacuum, as the water is used.  Then when the tub is used, the vacuum will refill the tank.  I have the valve system worked out, but the physics is over my head.

Basically the straw full of water with your finger over one end;
IF there is a gas bubble, can I get a gas to expand enough to let water out and create a vacuum?  Which gas is best?  Assume temp is constant (ish)

Any discussion of weight of the water and opening sizes is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

That question doesn't really make sense for several reasons.

First of all: All gases will expand to the whole volume of the vacuum chamber, so "which expands the most" doesn't make sense.

I think your question is which gas will produce the best vacuum if the volme doubles and for that: all gases will pretty much behave the same here. Double the volume, half the pressure.

Other than that: this setup won't ever work for a ton of reasons, the most obvious one: If the build up vacuum isn't strong enough to hold the water back from flowing out it won't be strong enough to suck water in. It also would be a perpetual motion machine, wich cannot exist.

Take a straw, put it in water and close the top hole with your finger. Then pull it out of the water. You will see that some of it comes out at the bottom, but a little bit stays in there. Why? Because there's a vacuum obove the water in the straw. So now put the bottom tip of the straw onto the water surface, it won't suck in additional water.